# Config not found: .kube/prod-k8s-clcreative-kubeconfig.yaml, .kube/civo-k8s_test_1-kubeconfig, .kube/k8s_test_1.yml

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

## Command `kubectl config get-contexts`

error:

`W0617 11:50:24.613103   12808 loader.go:222] Config not found: .kube/prod-k8s-clcreative-kubeconfig.yaml, .kube/civo-k8s_test_1-kubeconfig, .kube/k8s_test_1.yml CURRENT   NAME   CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE`

I am  trying to setup kubectl with docker desktop

*Tried*

- restarting kubernetes in docker desktop
- run the command in terminal with adminstrator

i expected it show the docker desktop as a context

and

when I tried to `kubectl get nodes`

I get this error:
`W0617 11:59:41.048676 23252 loader.go:222] Config not found: .kube/prod-k8s-clcreative-kubeconfig.yaml, .kube/civo-k8s_test_1-kubeconfig, .kube/k8s_test_1.yml

E0617 11:59:43.396988 23252 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

E0617 11:59:45.735625 23252 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

E0617 11:59:48.104304 23252 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

E0617 11:59:50.448120 23252 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

E0617 11:59:52.773207 23252 memcache.go:265] couldn't get current server API group list: Get "http://localhost:8080/api?timeout=32s": dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

Comment: Do you have a `$KUBECONFIG` environment variable set?

Comment: As @DavidMaze suggested, it sounds like you have the `$KUBECONFIG` variable set in your environment. While this can point to multiple files, it needs to be colon-separated rather than comma-separated (`/path/to/file1:/path/to/file2:...`). Because it can't find a valid config file, `kubectl` is defaulting to a server address of `localhost:8080`, which is obviously incorrect.

Comment: no, I haven't added an environmental variable,
I am following a Udemy  course, in which the instructor enables Kubernetes from the docker desktop(windows), and started using Kubectl,

Comment: i don't what's the real issue, but It has something to do with terminal, i was running this in  powershell 7.2 as an admin when I got the error

but  it's working fine in cmd (I don't know why)
docker is using wsl2 in backed for the docker

Answer (score 0):

used windows cmd(admin) instead of PowerShell (admin)